# Fetch Data After Successful Login using Retrofit

Tags: android, authentication, retrofit

I have written user `Registration` function using **Retrofit**, and successfully `inserted` data into **Database**.

I just wrote user `Login` function and now would like to know how could I `fetch user id` using username and password

```
public interface LoginAPI {
   @POST("/login.php")
   public void checkLogin(String username,String password,Callback<LoginResponse> response);    
}
```

Code:

```
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    Thread fetch = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

               RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(BASE_URL)
                .build();


        LoginAPI api = restAdapter.create(LoginAPI.class);
        api.checkLogin(username,password,new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void success(LoginResponse loginResponse, Response response) {
                Log.d("Response","Logged In");
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Log.d("Response","Failed");

            }
        });
    }
  }

});
```

**Table** contains following `fields`:

**1.** user_id
**2.** username
**3.** password

Comment: LoginResponse should have setter and getter methods. Use them. Basically LoginResponse should contain everything that user sends to client.

Comment: can you also add the LoginResponse class. As @cgr says, it should contain a getter and setter (or fields should be public).

Comment: can you post your complete response ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LoginResponse might be:

```
    public class LoginResponse {

private int user_id ;
private String username;
private String password;



public int getUser_id() {
    return user_id;
}

public void setUser_id(int user_id) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

}

and how to get it ?

```
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

Thread fetch = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

           RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(BASE_URL)
            .build();


    LoginAPI api = restAdapter.create(LoginAPI.class);
    api.checkLogin(username,password,new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void success(LoginResponse loginResponse, Response response) {              
            if(loginResponse != null){
             Log.d("Response",loginResponse.getUserName());
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Log.d("Response","Failed");

        }
    });
}
     }

   });
```